# How to maintain syntax highlighting in foldtext in vim using SimplyFold?

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting, folding, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using [this](https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold) vim plugin for folding which is great and very simple however one issue I've noticed is that the headers all end up losing syntax highlighting as they are returned as part of the foldtext.

I was wondering if it is possible to maintain syntax highlighting in the foldtext in some way.

Given only `def`s `class`es and docstrings are being folded it shouldn't be too difficult but I don't even know where to start.

It seems like `set foldtext` is the relevant command but not sure about much beyond that.

This is what the folding currently looks like showing the lack of syntaax highlighting in the foldtext.

[image]

Please let me know how I could do this thank you

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting works on the actual buffer contents. If you fold lines, syntax highlighting does not work on those lines any longer, and the entire fold summary (that is determined by `'foldtext'`) is highlighted with the [`:help hl-Folded`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-Folded) highlight group. Unfortunately, there's no way around it right now.

Implementing this in Vim raises some hard questions:

- Syntax highlighting can be dependent on previous / following lines. How many (in closed fold) would you still parse? If there are many large closed folds on the screen, this could mean a lot of parsing, much more than is usually needed just for the visible part inside the window.
- You still want an indication of those lines being folded. As syntax highlighting can use the same set of available attributes and colors as the `Folded` highlight group, there's no general solution on how to combine both. "Overlaying" or "adding" colors is difficult, especially in terminals with only 16 available colors.